# Bot is not responding to @Mention when sending message using Graph API

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, bots, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have created and deployed a bot in Microsoft Teams. Bot Works properly and responds when user talks to the bot using @Mention (e.g. @mybot) in a channel. I just tried to send message to the bot using graph API call:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{group-id-for-teams}/channels/{channel-id}/messages

**Method**: `POST`

**Content-type**: `application/json`

**Body**:

```
"body": {
    "contentType": "html",
    "content": "Hello World <at id=\"0\">standupbot</at>"
  },
  "mentions": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "mentionText": "StandupBot",
      "mentioned": {
        "application": {
                            "id": "[my-bot-id]",
                            "displayName": "StandupBot",
                            "applicationIdentityType": "bot"
                        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The Post request goes well, message is posted in my team and bot gets mentioned. But bot is not responding to the mention. However, if user manually mentions the bot in team then bot responds.

What is wrong here, Am i missing something or is it a bug? Please guide.

**P.S:** I am using Graph Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. We could repro the issue on our side and we have raised a bug for this. We are working on this.

Comment: This seems to be a bug as I am getting the same issue as you.