# Microsoft Teams. Using Python to message specific co-workers. Possible?

Tags: python, active-directory, microsoft-teams

I am helping my employer by co-ordinating the roll out of a new version of Windows. For a little bit more context see [Working with a list of AD 'displayNames' in Powershell. How to indicate which users were not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70364825/working-with-a-list-of-ad-displaynames-in-powershell-how-to-indicate-which-us)

I have sent several co-workers requests (by email) to ask them to simply update. 90% of these emails seem to go simply ignored. I can easily verify who has or has not acted with a PS script.

I have stated using Teams instead. A far, far higher reaction rate.

I can 'semi' automate the process, by saving the names of the computers that are not up to date, their version of Windows and assigned employee into a XLS file and then use **xlrd** and **pyautogui** libraries in Python to read the file, manipulate the cursor and send the staff member in question a personalised greeting (asking them nicely to just get it over and done with!).

Is there any way that I can automate this even further? I have researched API ways of doing things but it always seems to be at the team/channel level. I'm not looking for a 'public' broadcast, but rather to contact just one person.

Thanks, William

Comment: I actually have a personal API that I use to send emails to my mom, so I think you can just create an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I doubt that this will answer the question, it looks like I may be out of luck... I don't have access the Azure admin portal for the company I work for... (amongst other things).

[Create MS Teams chats with MS Graph (or PowerShell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59561168/create-ms-teams-chats-with-ms-graph-or-powershell)

Comment: Well the issue isn't resolved per se. but I doubt that much more can be done from my end (or from anyone on StackOverflow). I don't have the admin rights. And programming 'bots' etc is over my head!

Comment: I'll accept my own answer tomorrow. The system won't let me do it today. Thanks for your enquiry about the matter.