# Send Proactive 1:1 message in Teams using Bot Framework V4

Tags: .net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams, proactive

I'm trying to send proactive 1:1 message from bot to teams using Teams SDK with the code below

```
MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl);
            var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl), Configuration["MicrosoftAppId"], Configuration["MicrosoftAppPassword"]);

            var userId = _operation.MemberTeamsId;
            var tenantId = Configuration["TenantId"];
            var parameters = new ConversationParameters
            {
                Members = new[] { new ChannelAccount(userId) },
                ChannelData = new TeamsChannelData
                {
                    Tenant = new TenantInfo(tenantId),
                },
            };

            var conversationResource = await connectorClient.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(parameters);
            var message = Microsoft.Bot.Schema.Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
            message.Text = _operation.Message;
            await connectorClient.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(conversationResource.Id, (Microsoft.Bot.Schema.Activity)message);
```

I have the following issues with this,

1. **The bot cannot send a proactive message unless the user has a prior conversation after deployment**

   ***Bot deployed***

   Bill to Bot - Works

   Bot to Bill - Works

   ***Bot redeployed***

   Bot to Bill - Not works because there are no members in the conversation now after redeploying

   Bill to Bot - Works

   Bot to Bill - Works now as Bill had a conversation after redeploying
2. **Bot sends the same message multiple times to users**

   Bill to Bot - Works

   Bot to Bill - Works Proactively - Sends 1 defined message as it should

   Sim to Bot - Works

   Bot to Sim - Sends 2 same messages as there are two members in the conversation now

   Will to Bot - works

   Bot to Will - Sends 3 same messages as there are three members in the conversation now

**Note: I am storing the Teams userid in DB and use them to send direct messages to users**

Any help on how to correct this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not actually clear on what you exact *question* is, but I'm guessing it's that you don't want multiple messages sent? Or, do you want them sent directly to the users, instead of to the group chat? Or do you want them sent to the group chat, but only one message?

Comment: I'm trying to send 1:1 Personal messages to users from Bot. The bot is unable to send messages to the user who hasn't conversed after deployment. And If it's able to send after conversed, it is sending the same messages multiple times according to the number of users who have already conversed with the bot, I.e. If there are 10 users conversed with bot after deployment, BOT will send the desired message to the desired user 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answers in the comments, I think I understand the scenario better, and it looks to me like the problem is that you're not setting a Conversation Id anyway - although you tell the Bot which *user* you want to interact with, it needs to know if you want to interact with them *directly* (i.e. 1-1), or as part of a group chat somewhere, or a Teams channel.

You need to set this by configuring the Conversation property on the Activity instance (in your case the "message" variable). See my post here for more detailed information: [Programmatically sending a message to a bot in Microsoft Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370644/programmatically-sending-a-message-to-a-bot-in-microsoft-teams/59439602#59439602)

Hope that helps - if not, let me know