# How do i send a message to everyone in the team privately ? (Teams Bot)

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

What I need to achieve is so simple yet too complicated, I can't simply send a message to members in my team

I've been trying to develop a chat bot for my community that sends a message to everyone in the organization team regularly from time to time, which I've come to conclusion that what I need to achieve is called "Proactive Messages"
I've tried everything and checked every example and the docs, every time i just fail because of deprecated functions, api permissions, can't get a list of all members in the team, cant send the actual message even if i manage to get conversation id

I just want a straightforward javascript code that i use, with my app id, password, and team id to achieve my goal , with a function that does the following -> get all members in the team, loop through them, and send them a private message, whenever i want

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838826/send-proactive-11-message-in-teams-using-bot-framework-v4?rq=2) thread where the scenario of sending message to everyone privately is explained in details.