# clientSecret can not be null while sending a conversation pro-active message to Microsoft Teams

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'll to send a <s>notification</s> *pro-active message* when something is changed by a bot that is linked to Microsoft Teams. The demo uses *(for be simple)* only an API endpoint on the bot website.

After I've started a conversation, I store that in the conversation to a property called `MemoryVariables.ConversationReferences` *(type of `ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference>`)*.

When I browse to the API endpoint, then I see that there comes no message however I've got a 200 response. While looking for the bug I've added a breakpoint on marked line.

```cs
public class AdapterWithErrorHandler : BotFrameworkHttpAdapter
{
    public AdapterWithErrorHandler(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<BotFrameworkHttpAdapter> logger : base(configuration, logger)
    {
        OnTurnError = async (turnContext, exception) =>
        {
            logger.LogError(exception, $"[OnTurnError] unhandled error : {exception.Message}"); // <-- breakpoint added here
        };
    }
}
```

There I see that I've next exception:

> **`System.ArgumentNullException`:** Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: `clientSecret`

Here's the stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential..ctor(String clientId, String clientSecret)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.MicrosoftAppCredentials.<BuildAuthenticator>b__14_0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.AppCredentials.GetTokenAsync(Boolean forceRefresh)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.AppCredentials.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityWithHttpMessagesAsync(String conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConversationsExtensions.ReplyToActivityAsync(IConversations operations, String conversationId, String activityId, Activity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.SendActivitiesAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, Activity[] activities, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<<SendActivitiesAsync>g__SendActivitiesThroughAdapter|1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.SendActivityAsync(IActivity activity, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MyDemoBot.Bot.Controllers.NotifyController.BotCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\MyDemoBot\Savaco.KBESAVAC.NotificationBot.Bot\Controllers\NotifyController.cs:line 59
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.TenantIdWorkaroundForTeamsMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.MiddlewareSet.ReceiveActivityWithStatusAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.RunPipelineAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Below you've my `NotifyController` where the exception is thrown on marked line.

```cs
[Route("api/notify")]
[ApiController]
public class NotifyController : ControllerBase
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        MemoryVariables memoryVariables = MemoryVariables.GetInstance();
        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
        ICollection<ConversationReference> conversationReferences = memoryVariables.ConversationReferences.Values;

        foreach (ConversationReference conversationReference in conversationReferences)
        {
            taskList.Add(memoryVariables.BotAdapter.ContinueConversationAsync(
                conversationReference.Bot.Id,
                conversationReference,
                BotCallback,
                new CancellationToken()
            ));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(taskList); // <-- exceptions throws on this line code

        return GetContentResult(new { messagesSend = conversationReferences.Count }, HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    private ContentResult GetContentResult(object content, HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode)
    {
        return new ContentResult()
        {
            Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content),
            ContentType = "application/json",
            StatusCode = (int)httpStatusCode
        };
    }

    private async Task BotCallback(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(
            MessageFactory.SuggestedActions(
                new string[] { "Create A", "Create B" },
                "Hi, you've received a notification. Choose an action from below to continue."
            ),
            cancellationToken
        );
    }
}
```

Did I miss anything in my code or is there anything specifiek for Microsoft Teams I've missed? Using localhost and the Bot Framework Emulator, I don't have a problem with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are a few things to consider here. First of all, storing this in memory is a problem if you app recycles for any reason - you might want to store it more persistently rather (e.g. database). In addition, I'd suggest reading my blog post (new blog engine so it's a bit sparse right now) on [How Bots Calls Actually Work](https://hilton.giesenow.com/how-bot-calls-actually-work) as it will help to explain the pieces that you're currently missing.

In essence, if you're not replying directly to an existing message, and you want to send a message at *another later time* from your bot, then it's referred to as "pro-active messaging" and to do this you need more than just the conversation reference, you need a few other bits of info as well. I've described more about this, with links and sample code, over at [Programmatically sending a message to a bot in Microsoft Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370644/programmatically-sending-a-message-to-a-bot-in-microsoft-teams/59439602#59439602).

Hope that helps