# Is there a way in Teams to stop people posting to a channel without using a Bot message extension

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

I'm currently creating a Message Extension bot for our escalation channel in Teams and would like it so our company has to use the Bot messaging extension to log escalation issues, this is to help our dev team gather as much information about issues as possible. When other departments log issues straight into the channel important information is sometimes missed out, causing us to lose time asking. Does anyone know a way of achieving this functionality?

[image: Image of the message extension bot]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, unfortunately, and the bot doesn't automatically receive every message in the channel either.

Perhaps you could look at an alternative: have the users connect to the bot directly, in 1-1 conversations, and whatever they log via the bot, the bot could -repost- into the channel as a pro-active message (I've posted some steps on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370644/programmatically-sending-a-message-to-a-bot-in-microsoft-teams/59439602#59439602)).

In your bot, you could show an adaptive card to help with data entry, but I suppose you're doing something like that already with the message extension? If so, you can just re-use the same card.