# Microsoft Teams proactive messaging in activity feed

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a requirement that my bot should receive a notification from an external system and then it needs to send notification to Teams' logged in user's activity feed.

I followed https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages, it works on emulator. I deployed above app on on-premise IIS server (with https support) and then registered on https://dev.botframework.com/ by providing botid generated through MSTeams App builder. Now, when I sideloaded this bot in MS Teams, it does not send proactive message.

I am new to Bot framework hence steps by steps instructions and sample code will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more details.
Once test your bot in botframework if it works there.

Comment: Please share the manifest used during side loading.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given a lot of detail in your question about your actual setup, or the code you're using, so it's hard to really answer, but I have posted a few time recently about pro-active messaging. Here's one with a bunch of detail, in C#, so hopefully it can help: [Programmatically sending a message to a bot in Microsoft Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370644/programmatically-sending-a-message-to-a-bot-in-microsoft-teams/59439602#59439602) - just see my answer in that page. If that doesn't help, please try describe your current scenario better, and what you've tried.

Comment: Thanks I got solution by following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370644/programmatically-sending-a-message-to-a-bot-in-microsoft-teams/59439602#59439602

Comment: Great, glad you got it working! As this helped, please "mark as answer"