# Microsoft Bot Builder - send proactive message to user

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I am trying to create a to-do app for microsoft Teams. Whenever a new task is created inside a team, this task is saved to team's sharepoint and i want to use a chat bot to notify all members of this team that " a new task is created". The flow is somehow like Planner. If you are assigned to task in Planner, you'll receive immediately a message from Planner chat bot. Does any have idea, how can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

In essence, if you're not replying directly to an existing message, and you want to send a message at another later time from your bot, then it's referred to as "pro-active messaging", as you've said in the title. To do this, you need to capture certain information when the bot is added to the team (things like a "conversation reference", serviceurl, and a few other bits of info as well). I've described more about this, with links and sample code, over at [Programmatically sending a message to a bot in Microsoft Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370644/programmatically-sending-a-message-to-a-bot-in-microsoft-teams/59439602#59439602). Of course, start first with the docs themselves, such as [Send Proactive Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#send-proactive-message).

Comment: Was this answer of help to you?