# Can I set a timer to go off in an MS Teams channel?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm using MS Teams for audio communications in meetings. I use one channel for the main meeting. I use additional channels, with meetings going in each one, as "break-out rooms" for independent, small group conversations. I'm wondering if I can set a timer to 'ping' the break-out channels to indicate it's time to come back together in the main channel. If not a timer, is there a way to delay send a message to a channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing built-in to Teams for this, but there are a few ways to accomplish it programmatically:

1) You can create a bot that, when added to the channel, will immediately get "contact" details to message the channel whenever it wants (e.g. Now + 30 minutes). This is called "Pro-active messaging" and I've given some details of how to do this at [Programmatically sending a message to a bot in Microsoft Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370644/programmatically-sending-a-message-to-a-bot-in-microsoft-teams/59439602#59439602). Let me know if you want more guidance on this approach (especially if you've not built a bot before).

2) You can configure [Incoming Webhooks for Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook), and then just call that webhook from whatever app you want (or even a script like PowerShell)

3) You could have Flow (Power Automate) send a message to the channel.

Options 2 & 3 require the channel to exist beforehand, and for everything to be configured beforehand as well, but they're the easiest, especially if you've not built bots before. Option 1 is the most work, but end users can simply add the bot at the time they start the "breakout" and everything will happen automatically.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in-built that you can use directly to address your requirement. The best way to handle this is create Flow. Check [Flow Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/get-started-logic-flow).