# Teams Bot how to listen on incoming calls?

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams

I am getting lost in all the documentation available on my first time attempting to set up a Microsoft Teams bot. I have it set up and able to write command activated messages in personal, groups and teams. I need to transition this to be able to receive a payload of data (the data that I will use to populate my activity card), but I can't figure out how am I supposed to let the bot know which Group or Team the payload is ment for.

The payload will be sent from my Azure hosted API, to the endpoint of my Bot. It should then, with some data in the payload I suppose, know which group or team to sent the processed activity card to?

If you could provide me with the documentation I need to read up on, or further explanation on how to proceed, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview) try if that helps

Comment: Did you chcek the Docs? Are you still looking into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this using the answers from this thread:
[Programmatically sending a message to a bot in Microsoft Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370644/programmatically-sending-a-message-to-a-bot-in-microsoft-teams)

Specifically thanks to the message from @Hilton Giesenow:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59439602/10429879

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to teams bot for incoming calls,
Bots can interact with Teams calls and meetings using real-time voice, video, and screen sharing. With Microsoft Graph APIs for calls and online meetings, Teams apps can now interact with users using voice and video to enhance the experience. These APIs allow you to add the following new features:

Interactive voice response (IVR).
Call control.
Access to real-time audio and video streams, including desktop and app sharing.

please check this [doc](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples) for more info and [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples)

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the delay in responding to you.

I read the documentation you sent, but I am not sure how it relates as I do not need real-time voice, audio or screen sharing capabilities.

I can understand that the title writing "incoming calls" could be cause of misunderstanding, however, the issue is as described that I need to forward a payload from my API endpoint that needs to be received in the Teams Bot that listens to that specific payload. I don't know how to approach a solution for that part, after that part the Teams Bot should then sendActivity with an activity card attachment (this I have prepared already using dummy data and the card designer for layout), containing that payload data, to the group/team that the Teams Bot is active on.